# The precision of the natural logarithm is not correct in CLISP. What might be wrong?

Tags: math, lisp, floating-point, precision

What went wrong?

```
 [1]> (log (exp 1))
 0.99999994
```

Comment: Welcome to the joy of floating point numbers. Look at the "related" column on the right side of this page for many many many explanations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to the finite precision of floating-point representations of fractional numbers.

Please see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

`(exp 1)` is going to be an approximation of `e` (which requires infinite precision to represent perfectly).  The natural logarithm of that approximation will be approximately (but not exactly) `1`.  Understanding floating-point representation will allow you to understand why this happens.

CLISP is using your machine architecture's native representation of floats.  Most commonly by far, this representation is in one the formats specified by [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) (typically 32- or 64-bit; in your case it looks like 32-bit).  In a nutshell, fractional parts are represented by a sum of inverse powers of 2 (*i.e.*, some combination of `1/2`, `1/4`, `1/8`, ... `1/2^32`, *etc.*)

Answer (score 2):

Try with double precision floating point:

`(log (exp 1.0d0))`

=> `1.0D0` ; at least in Clozure CL

Comment: There will be rounding issues with any finite floating point precision. If you get the "correct" result, there are two likely explanations. First - you are lucky with the rounding, but would get an error for (log (exp 1.5d0)) or some other number. Second, there is decimal rounding applied for display purposes which is giving a lucky result, but would give an error for other starting value. The unlikely possibility is symbolic math, avoiding the numeric calculation completely. This is rare outside of the languages built into a few specialist apps.